# App stops working with signed APK playstore version but does work from the compiled one from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, proguard

When I login in the timetable page, from the version downloaded from android studio onto my phone, it works fine and takes me to the timetable. However when I try login in the timetable page from the version downloaded from the playstore, it just loads forever.

So is there anyway I could possibly test the version downloaded from the playstore by viewing messages in the console? (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead)

Here's the entire source code: https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead

This is where it stalls and never logs in - The login button onclick listener: (https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gmail/gogobebe2/thedayahead/timetable/TimetableFragment.java#L192):

```
    @SuppressLint({"AddJavascriptInterface", "SetJavaScriptEnabled"})
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId() == R.id.login_button) {
            if (kmarDocument == null) initKmarLoginConnection();
            else {
                EditText usernameEditText = (EditText) loginRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText_username);
                EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) loginRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.editText_password);

                updateLoginPreferences((CheckBox) loginRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_rememberMe),
                        usernameEditText, passwordEditText);

                WebView webView = new WebView(getContext());

                webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                webView.clearCache(true);
                webView.clearHistory();
                clearCookies(this);

                webView.addJavascriptInterface(new HTMLRetrieverJavaScriptInterface(this), "HtmlRetriever");

                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadResource(WebView webView, String destinationUrl) {
                        CheckBox rememberMeCheckbox = (CheckBox) loginRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkBox_rememberMe);
                        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) loginRelativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        rememberMeCheckbox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        super.onLoadResource(webView, destinationUrl);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String urlLoaded) {
                        final String LOGIN_JAVASCRIPT = "javascript:document.getElementById(\"loginSubmit\").click()";
                        final String HTML_RETRIEVER_JAVASCRIPT = "javascript:window.HtmlRetriever.showHTML" +
                                "('<html>' + document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML + '</html>');";
                        if (urlLoaded.equals(KMAR_TIMETABLE_URL)) {
                            // debug: webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            webView.loadUrl(HTML_RETRIEVER_JAVASCRIPT);
                        } else if (!urlLoaded.equals(LOGIN_JAVASCRIPT)) {
                            webView.loadUrl(LOGIN_JAVASCRIPT);
                        }
                    }
                });

                WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
                webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

                loginRelativeLayout.addView(webView);

                Element loginUsernameElement = kmarDocument.getElementById("loginUsername");
                Element loginPasswordElement = kmarDocument.getElementById("loginPassword");

                loginUsernameElement.attr("value", usernameEditText.getText().toString());
                loginPasswordElement.attr("value", passwordEditText.getText().toString());

                webView.loadData(kmarDocument.html(), "text/html", "UTF-8");

                // I then call the click() function on the loginSubmit button when the page is finished
                // loading in the overridden onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) method.
            }
        }
}
```

Here's the proguard file. I don't know if I did this right but I've seen on other stack overflow questions similar to mine that the problem was usually with this. (https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro):

```
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in /home/william/Android/Sdk/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the proguardFiles
# directive in build.gradle.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
-keepclassmembers class com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead.timetable.TimetableFragment$HTMLRetrieverJavaScriptInterface {
   public *;
}
```

Here's the JavascriptInterface (https://github.com/gogobebe2/TheDayAhead/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/gmail/gogobebe2/thedayahead/timetable/TimetableFragment.java#L177):

```
public class HTMLRetrieverJavaScriptInterface {
        TimetableFragment timetableFragment;

        HTMLRetrieverJavaScriptInterface(TimetableFragment timetableFragment) {
            super();
            this.timetableFragment = timetableFragment;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        void showHTML(String html) {
            kmarTimetableHTML = html;
            MainActivity.timetable = new Timetable(kmarTimetableHTML, timetableFragment);
        }
}
```

**EDIT:**
In `build.gradle` I changed `minifyEnabled` from `false` to `true`. Now, with the one downloaded from the play store, when I navigate to the timetable page the app just fully crashes. However if I use the one I downloaded from android studio, it works fine.

Comment: Did you get any kind of error message? And the version downloaded from the playstore is updated?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I made an edit. Also, how do I see any errors from the one downloaded from the playstore? It doesn't crash at all when downloaded from android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved myself.

**New Javascript interface class:**

```
    @Keep
    public class HTMLRetrieverJavaScriptInterface {
        TimetableFragment timetableFragment;

        public HTMLRetrieverJavaScriptInterface(TimetableFragment timetableFragment) {
            super();
            this.timetableFragment = timetableFragment;
        }

        @Keep
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showHTML(String html) {
            kmarTimetableHTML = html;
            MainActivity.timetable = new Timetable(kmarTimetableHTML, timetableFragment);
        }
}
```

**New pro-guard file:**

```
-keepclassmembers class com.gmail.gogobebe2.thedayahead.timetable.TimetableFragment$HTMLRetrieverJavaScriptInterface {
   public *;
}
-keepattributes JavascriptInterface
```